# Is there any notation used for saying that we're using non-classical logic like paraconsistent logic?

Tags: logic, soft-question

Is there any notation used for saying that we're using non-classical logic like paraconsistent logic? If we're making a mathematical statement using mathematical symbols, but we want to specify that we're not using classical mathematical logic to set out the conditions or making any mathematical statement using symbols, is there any symbols we can use to specify what logic we're using for the mathematical statement or claim?

Example:

> Given condition X and Y and the fact we're using paraconsistent logic,
> then A and B must be true.

Comment: Why do you want to use symbols instead of words?

Comment: In formal logic arguments one can subscript the turnstile symbol with the logical system, so for example, in Intuitionistic Logic (IL) we can prove $(---P) \vdash_{\text{IL}} (-P)$ but we can't prove $(--P) \vdash_{\text{IL}} P,$ whereas in Classical Logic (CL) we can prove both $(---P) \vdash_{\text{CL}} (-P)$ and $(--P) \vdash_{\text{CL}} P.$ However, I suspect that in less formal situations involving ordinary mathematical proofs, it would be difficult to [stay the course](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/stay-the-course) **(continued)**

Comment: when using a specific paraconsistent logic in the metalanguage. For example, the use of counterexamples would be seriously curtailed I think.